# Add custom menus to magento

Tags: magento-1.7, theme, layout, template, menu

I need to add menus like here http://www.pickormiss.com as given here like Vegetables, Meatshops, Restaurant, Gift shops etc.  How can I add such pages so, that it can be customized from the dashboard?

Comment: You are talking about the menu sub descriptions here, right? ie the normal menu link would be 'Vegetables', you want to be able to add the 'perfectly fresh!' to the main menu as well and style that text differently?

Comment: Yes, now only the existing category list are listed as menu. But I want to add few links as per my choice and also it must be customized from  the dashboard.

Answer (score 2):

To add static pages to the menu you first need to create a statick block with the content, then create a category and on the **Display Settings** tab you change the **Display mode** to **Static Block only** and for **CMS Block** you select the created static block for that page.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest looking at the [TsDesign Menubuilder extension](http://www.tsdesigns.de/en/tsdesigns-menubuilder.html). It does a great job in making all sorts of menus manageable.